# 'Communications link failure The last packet sent…' when connecting to MySQL with Java

Tags: java, mysql

I have deployed my application and distributed onto a client windows computer. I have disabled my antivirus and windows firewall but why do i still get this error  'Communications link failure The last packet sent…' when connecting to MySQL?

I have successfully installed Java version 8. Do i have to also install Xampp on the client windows computer for the application to work?

Comment: Can you please add more details about the error. May be you put error stack-trace here.

Comment: If you want to connect to a mysql database of course you need to install it. XAMPP contains a lot of helpful software for deploying web applications. If you want to connect to a local database you also do not need to disable your firewall.

Comment: @HenryMartens, for clarification, you mean my client has to install Xampp on his computer in order for the java application to work?

Comment: @AshuPhaugat, the error above is what is showing on my client's computer. I am just a beginner. Is there a way to get the stack-trace? Because the application works fine on my computer

Comment: @Zlatan If your mysql database runs on a central server then you don't need to install XAMPP on your client. It is only necessary if you want to run your database on your local machine

Comment: @HenryMartens my mysql database is not on a central server. i created the application on local host and i just deployed and distributed the application to my client who doesn't have Xampp installed or any local database

Comment: @Zlatan Ok, so your client needs to connect to a database that runs on your machine. If you get no connection check the IP configured in your script or install XAMPP on local machine of your client.

Comment: @HenryMartens I will try to host my database on a free mysql hosting server if possible .

Answer (score 0):

Issue lies on the IP configuration, so first look for your IP address then
on your client's computer, put your IP. It would have helped if you sent the code on your computer and on your client's computer. On your computer you may have this, and it will work fine.

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
```

But on your client's computer since they are connecting to a database on your machine, it will be like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://xxx.xxx.x.x:3306/test
```

2. Check on your computer whether the MYSQL server is running.